# Overriding hashcode method to return hashcode of variable in a class

Tags: java, set, hashcode

```
class UserScoring implements Comparable<UserScoring> {

        User user;
        int score;

        UserScoring(User user, int score) {
            this.user = user;
            this.score = score;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(UserScoring o) {
            if (this.score < o.score) {
                return 1;
            }
            else if (this.score == o.score) {
                return 0;
            }
            return -1;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return user.hashCode();
        }

        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (obj == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
                return false;
            }
            final UserScoring other = (UserScoring) obj;

            return user.equals(other.user);
        }
    }
```

I want to create a class `UserScoring` which can be sorted on the basis of its variable score and whose uniqueness is determined by its user.

This means that :

1. If I sort a collection of UserScoring objects using Collections.sort(), I want the sorting based on score in a descending order. I have overriden the compareTo method for the same.
2. If I create a set of the UserScoring objects, I do not want two UserScoring objects of the same user. I have overriden the equals and the hashcode method for the same.

I have two doubts here: 
1. Is it wrong to return the hashcode of the UserScoring object the same as the User object. It sure looks wrong to me. But what are the problems it can cause?

2. Is there any way at all to make sure that only the UserScoring object of the higher score is kept in the set(and the object with less score is either evicted or not added) whenever there is an attempt to add two UserScoring objects of the same user.

   ```
   UserScoring us1 = new UserScoring(u1, 1000);
   UserScoring us2 = new UserScoring(u1, 100);
   Set<UserScoring> set = new HashSet<>();
   set.add(us1);
   set.add(us2);
   ```

How can this set contain us1 instead of us2?

Comment: hashCode and equals implementations have to match each other. Yours do not.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth In what sense do they have to match? What can I do here so they match?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I understand that this implementation is wrong because for two UserScoring objects with different score, it implies that they are equal and it should not. But I want to keep these objects in a set such that there is only one object for a single user. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Also, I would like to know why the question was downvoted. I am only trying to find a solution after explaining my problem and giving the erroneous solution I thought of.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth In what way to the `hashCode()` and `equals()` implementations not match? They're both just considering the `user` field. What **doesn't** match up is the `compareTo` implementation.

Comment: @khelwood What's wrong with the compareTo implementation?

Comment: @tanvi That you could have two objects that your `equals` method says are equal, but `compareTo` between them will not return 0. Your `compareTo` is not consistent with equality.

Comment: @khelwood ****facepalm**** I should be implementing a Comparator instead of course! Thanks a lot. Could you please also help me with keeping these objects in a set such that the set has only one object per user?

Comment: @tanvi I think you might be better off with a `Map<User, UserScoring>`. That way you can look up the `UserScoring` based on a `User`; have only one `UserScoring` per `User`; and you can explicitly keep the one with the higher score if that is what you want. Currently you are trying to use `equals` to group objects that you don't really consider equal.

Comment: @khelwood That makes sense. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @khelwood - Ah, I misread the code.  They don't match `compareTo`, but they do match each other.

Comment: "I have overriden [sic] the ... hashcode method" - no, you haven't. You overrode the `hashCode` method. There is no `hashcode` method in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Is it wrong to return the hashcode of the UserScoring object the same as the User object. It sure looks wrong to me. But what are the problems it can cause?

It is not wrong.  In this case, we say that the "identity" of the `UserScoring` object is the associated `User` object.  However, this requires that your `equals()` method must also honor this identity convention, so it must be implemented as `return Objects.equal( this.user, other.user )`.

> 2. Is there any way at all to make sure that the UserScoring object of the higher score is kept in the set whenever there is an attempt to add two UserScoring objects of the same user.

I do not think there is any way to automate this with an unmodified HashSet, but you can provide your own `Set` decorator (call it, say, `RankingSet`) which examines the object being added against the object already in the underlying `Set` and keeps the one with the higher rank. (The rank in your case being the score.) You can look around the interwebz for a CollectionDecorator that you can use to reduce the amount of work that you need to do: it will enable you to only override the `add()` method and let the rest of the methods be delegated to the underlying Set

Since you need to be able to compare your `UserScoring` objects, another problem you are likely to run into is that your `equals()` method does not agree with the result returned by `Comparable.compareTo()`.  One way to overcome this is by ***not*** making `UserScoring` comparable, and instead implementing a separate `Comparator` which compares `UserScoring` objects based on their score.

(So, the `RankingSet`  would need to receive such a `Comparator` as a constructor parameter.)

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike. This helps. I want to rephrase my question 2 "Is there any way at all to make sure that the UserScoring object of the higher score is kept in the set AND THE ONE WITH LESSER SCORE IS REMOVED whenever there is an attempt to add two UserScoring objects of the same user." I don't want to keep two objects with same user.

Comment: I see.  I do not think there is any way to automate this with an unmodified HashSet, but you can provide your own `RankingSet` decorator which examines the object being added against the object already in the underlying `Set` and keeps the one with the higher rank.  (The rank being determined by a supplied `Comparator`.)  You can look around the interwebz for a `CollectionDecorator` that you can use to reduce the amount of work that you need to do: it will enable you to only override the `add()` method and let the rest of the methods be delegated to the underlying `Set`.

Comment: I have heard about the decorator pattern but not used it. Thanks a ton @Mike. I will look this up.